# cannot deploy to Azure storage

Tags: deployment, azure

Im trying to deploy an app into Azure, its basically a completely fresh vanilla cloud app with an ASP.NET webrole created in VS2010.

When I try to create a new hosted service and I choose the files created by the publish step, all I ever get is

"Uploading the selected package has failed, please verify your network connection and try again"

"The upload was unsuccessful"

My network is fine, but I dont know how to get past this issue... the uploaded files are no bigger than 3MB

Comment: Are you using new windows azure portal (the one, which is implemented with Silverlight)?

Comment: yep, and Im just trying IE9 which for some reason seems to be working... but not in Chrome

Comment: I agree with @Tarkus.  Much easier to deploy through VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you may want to deploy your Azure projects from inside Visual Studio. It's much easier.. Just right click on your cloud project in Solution Explorer > Publish.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff683672.aspx

Comment: I see, I actually avoided that because usually those things are flakey at best, but Ill give it a shot

Comment: ill mark this as the answer because it does work, but switching to IE also worked for me too

Comment: I had problems using Chrome, using IE worked and publishing from visual studio also did.